# Override SimpleMembershipProvider's FormsAuth ticket to include extra user info

Tags: c#, security, asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

I'm using the default functionality in ASP.NET MVC 4 app with SimpleMembershipProvider and was wondering how to add extra parameters (userId, etc.) to the cookie that is created when a user logs in? Can I simply override the cookie?